# Conflicts between databases

Tags: c#, sql, dbml

I have an automation project that I use for several similar sites.
The databases of the sites are also similar beside the `USERS` table.

In one database the table `USERS` has the column `Fname`, in the other one this column is not present. In the other database I have a column named `RegesrationDate` and in others this column is not present. etc. etc.

When I am running a query I get the error

> specified cast is not valid.

because I can't cast the return value (which has more columns then I am holding in my `dbml` file).

There is a way in my project to make a generic `dbml` object that I will run:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
```

and to get a normal object. Do you have other ideas how to make my project work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first approach:

My suggestion is to remove all unique fields and get the generic table at first. 
After that, use db.ExecuteQuery for the unique fields every special db.

second: 
It's not generic db, therefore use two (or more) user table on your dbml file.

userDb1 table, userDb2 table....

in c# do:

```
    if(dbname == 1){
        var a =db.userdb1.select()....
    }
```